# How "make" command locates makefile

Tags: unix, makefile

I am trying to understand the working of "make" command (just started on this command). I have an ".sh" file which has a script to execute "make" command as shown below:

```
source /somepath/environment-setup-cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi
make arch=arm toolchainPrefix=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi- xeno=off mode=Debug all
```

The directory where the script file is located has a file named "makefile". but there is nothing specified in the script file above regarding this "makefile". After executing the script file, all the script withing "makefile" is executed automatically. Can someone explain the working of "make xyz all" command in few words.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Makefile-Names

Comment: thank you Biffen. It has the information I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As often with UNIX systems the command works to some degree by conventions. `make` (the `GNU` version of `make` at least) will search the working directory for files called `GNUmakefile`, `makefile`, and `Makefile` in that order or you can use the `-f` (or `--file`) option to give it a specific file.